# Python IOError: File not open for writing and global name 'w' is not defined

Tags: python, io, syntax-error

I'm trying to write a little procedure that write (append would be even better) a line in a file with Python, like this:

```
def getNewNum(nlist):
    newNum = ''
    for i in nlist:
        newNum += i+' ' 
    return newNum

def writeDoc(st):
    openfile = open("numbers.txt", w)
    openfile.write(st)

newLine =  ["44", "299", "300"]

writeDoc(getNewNum(newLine))
```

But when I run this, I get the error:

```
openfile = open("numbers.txt", w)
NameError: global name 'w' is not defined
```

If I drop the "w" paremeter, I get this other error:

```
line 9, in writeDoc
    openfile.write(st)
IOError: File not open for writing
```

I'm following exactly (I hope) what is [here](http://www.sthurlow.com/python/lesson10/).

The same occurs when I try to append the new line. How can I fix that?

Comment: Your `getNewNum` function should just be `' '.join(newLine)`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is in the [open()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) call in `writeDoc()` that file mode specification is not correct.

```
openfile = open("numbers.txt", w)
                               ^
```

The `w` needs to have (a pair of single or double) quotes around it, i.e.,

```
openfile = open("numbers.txt", "w")
                                ^
```

To quote from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) re file mode:

> The first argument is a string containing the filename.
>     The second argument is another ***string*** containing a  few characters
>     describing the way in which the file will be used.

**Re**: "If I drop the "w" paremeter, I get this other error: ..IOError: File not open for writing"

This is because if *no* file mode is specified the default value is `'r'`ead, which explains the message about the file not being open for "writing", it's been opened for "reading".

See this Python doc for more information on [Reading/Writing files](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and for the valid mode specifications.

Comment: D'oh! Can't believe I've been using Python for so long and I still make silly goofs like this (and then have to look up what's going wrong. I ended up omitting the mode entirely.)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to append data to a file but you are currently trying to set the option to write to the file, which will override an existing file.

> The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second
>   argument is another string containing a few characters describing the
>   way in which the file will be used. mode can be 'r' when the file will
>   only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same
>   name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data
>   written to the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the
>   file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r'
>   will be assumed if it’s omitted.

In addition, your implementation results in the `open()` method looking for a parameter declared as `w`.  However, what you want is to pass the string value to indicate the append option, which is indicated by a encased in quotes.

```
openfile = open("numbers.txt", "a")
```